# Wohin gehört das "nicht"?

Tags: word-order, grammaticality

Man tippt ja schnell mal einen Kommentar und im Nachhinein wundert man sich, ob der Satzbau passt.

Bsp.:

> Siehs als Hinweis, dass man sich **nicht** über diverse Kommentare
>   wundern muss, wenn die Artikel/Überschriften keinen Deut besser sind
>   ;)

oder

> Siehs als Hinweis, dass man sich über diverse Kommentare
>   **nicht** wundern muss, wenn die Artikel/Überschriften keinen Deut besser sind
>   ;)

Gibt es hier ein richtig oder falsch?

---

Edith meint:

Unter den 234 andren Fragen gab es tatsächlich eine ... (finde sie gerade nicht wieder).

Bei Variante 1 bezieht sich das "nicht" eher auf den Angesprochen, während es bei Variante 2 der Inhalt ist.

Comment: Es wurden hier schon [234 Fragen zum Thema "nicht + Position"](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=nicht+position) gestellt und beantwortet. War da denn wirklich keine einzige dabei, die deine Frage beantwortet?

Comment: Ich würde Variante 1 wählen. > Siehs als Hinweis, dass man sich nicht über diverse Kommentare wundern muss, wenn die Artikel/Überschriften keinen Deut besser sind ;)

Comment: »Ich würde« klingt nach »ich bin mir nicht sicher«. Kannst du bitte dem Fragesteller entweder etwas mehr Sicherheit vermitteln (z.B. durch Zitieren relevanter Regeln). Alternativ könntest du auch auf die andere Möglichkeit eingehen. Ist sie falsch? Oder ist sie zwar richtig, aber ungebräuchlich?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Beide Schreibweisen sind möglich. Die erste wird aber eher das sein, was der Fragesteller will

Comment: Ich teile zwar deine Vermutung, aber: Warum wird die erste Möglichkeit eher jene sein, die der Fragesteller will? Sagen die beiden Möglichkeiten genau dasselbe aus, oder sind sie in der Bedeutung verschieden? Das was ich an deiner Antwort kritisiere ist die Tatsache, dass sie lediglich deine persönliche Meinung widerspiegelt, ohne dann man daraus irgend eine Allgemeingültigkeit ableiten könnte. Bitte gib mir, dem Fragesteller und dem Rest der Welt eine für alle nachvollziehbare Erklärung dafür, dass die erste Möglichkeit die bessere ist.

Comment: Deine Erklärung sollte in der Antwort enthalten sein (also schrieb bitte keinen Kommentar, sondern editiere deine Antwort), und sie sollte so beschaffen sein, dass aufgrund deiner Antwort auch andere Leuten bei anderen Sätze mit ähnlichem Aufbau das Wort *»nicht«* an die richtige Stelle setzen können.

Comment: @Tim "Die erste wird aber eher das sein, was der Fragesteller will" Wie kommst du darauf? Wenn ich mit meiner Interpretation nicht daneben liege, wäre die 2. etwas distanzierter/höfflicher und in dem Zusammenhang angebrachter ;) Frage beantwortet. Danke.

Comment: Für mich ist der Unterschied minimal. Ich vermute, es geht u.a. um die Integration oder Nicht-Integration einer (hier präpositionalen) Satzergänzung ins Verb. Ich selbst würde den Satz spontan immer eher mit 'nicht brauchen zu' statt 'nicht müssen' formulieren. Google liefert für "brauchst du dich nicht über * zu wundern" 57 Treffer und für "brauchst du dich über * nicht zu wundern" 296. Ähnlicher Fall: Bei so einer Steilvorlage brauchst du auf (den) Spott nicht lange zu warten. Hier ist 'Spott' betont, im Analogbeispiel wären es die 'Kommentare'. Dies als Anregung zum Weiter-Abwägen.